# he literal 08 of type int is out of range in java

Tags: java

I understand that defining numbers with 0 in the beginning but it should happen after 8th in natural numbers like 09,010 etc. But why does below declaration giveshe `literal 08 of type int is out of  range`

```
int b=08;
```

Comment: 0 prefix indicates octal numbers, which only contain digits from 0 to 7.

Comment: Numbers beginning with 0 are considered octal.